# Inclusion of external js file and calling a function inside the external js file does not work with same script tag

Tags: javascript, html, dom

Why it is necessary to first include an external js file and call any functiont later on with new script tags ?

I am testing with the code:

test.html

```
<html>
<head>
</head>
<body>
    <script src=test.js>test();</script>
</body>
</html>
```

test.js

```
function test(){
    alert(1);
}
```

**It does not show an alert popup.**

But when I include **test.js** separately either in **body or head** with the code:

test.html

```
<html>
<head>
</head>
<body>
    <script src=test.js></script>
    <script>test();</script>
</body>
</html>
```

It does show a pop-up indeed. Does it have anything to do with the HTML parser? I am not even getting a ReferenceError displayed in the browser console so test has a reference but it is not executing.

Comment: The script source is _either_ in an external file, or inline. Never both at the same time in the same `<script>` tag. See [the red warning in this documentation](https://developer.mozilla.org/en-US/docs/Web/HTML/Element/script).

Comment: Yes, as per the documentation it clearly says this. But I know the underlying reason why ? Any idea if this is related to the way HTML is being parsed ?

Comment: Did you read the explanation? "The unexpected behavior is _because_ it is only the JavaScript in the file referenced in the `src` attribute that will be added to the HTML page.". That's all there is to it. So if there is a `src` attribute the inline script will be ignored.

Answer (score 0):

Code in the global namespace must be loaded in the order such that executed code must first be defined.

For example, if a.js had...

```
var a = function() {
   alert('a');
}
```

...and b.js had...

```
a()
```

...then you wouldn't want to include b.js before a.js, or a() won't be available.

For above,

```
<script src=test.js></script>
<script>test();</script>
```

again it is the same way: First include file, then run its contents.

Comment: but isn't <script src="test.js">test()</script> loads test.js before test was called ?

Answer (score 0):

this happens because when you specify a src attribute you told the browser not to look for javascript inside this tag but instead from an external one